# How to pass an argument to a thread that asks for user input?

Tags: python, multithreading, automation, user-input

I am trying to automatize the execution of sqlmapapi (see [here](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap)). My program so far looks very simple and dumb:

```
def host():
    system("sqlmapapi -s -H 0.0.0.0")

def client():
    system("sqlmapapi -c -H 127.0.0.1")


def run():
    host_thread = Thread(target = host, args=())
    host_thread.start()
    time.sleep(5)

    client_thread = Thread(target=client, args=())
    client_thread.start()
    time.sleep(5)

run()
```

As soon as both threads are running, `api>` shows up to wait for my user input (which, e.g., could be `?` for help option). Is it possible to define my user input over my script and pass it to my client thread so that I could, e.g., open the help option automatically?

Edit: Since it doesn't seem to be clear - putting "?" into `args` does not work. The client is started by my thread and and as soon as it's up, it is running it will wait for an input.

Just to make you understand how it looks:

```
[01:32:53] [INFO] Starting REST-JSON API client to 'http://127.0.0.1:8775'...
[01:32:53] [DEBUG] Calling 'http://127.0.0.1:8775'
[01:32:53] [INFO] Type 'help' or '?' for list of available commands
api>
```

Comment: What would you expect the `args` argument to do? If not sure, what does `Thread` documentation say?

Comment: When I pass "?" to my client thread nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `?` as an argument. I'm not familiar with `sqlmapapi`, so make sure to format the command correctly.

```
def host(arg):
    system("sqlmapapi -s -H 0.0.0.0 {}".format(arg))

def client(arg):
    system("sqlmapapi -c -H 127.0.0.1 {}".format(arg))


def run():
    host_thread = Thread(target = host, args=('?',))
    host_thread.start()
    time.sleep(5)

    client_thread = Thread(target=client, args=('?',))
    client_thread.start()
    time.sleep(5)

run()
```